# React: How to create state dependent function in functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-functional-component

In my application I have component like that:

```
const MyComponent = props => {

    const { attrOneDefault, attrTwoDefault, formControl } = props;  
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
        attr_one: attrOneDefault,
        attr_two: attrTwoDefault
    });

    const getValue = ( attr ) => {
        return inputValue[attr];
    }
    const setValue = ( attr, val ) => {
        if( attr === 'attr_one' ) {
            if( val === 'bar' && getValue(attr) !== 'foo' ) {
                val = 'foo bar';
            }
        }
        setInputValue( {...inputValue, [attr]: val} );
    }

    useEffect( () => {
        if( formControl ) {         
            Object.keys(inputValue).forEach( attribute => {
                formControl.subscribeToValueCollecting( attribute, () => {
                    return getValue(attribute);
                });
                formControl.subscribeToValueChange( attribute, ( value ) => {
                    setValue( attribute, value );
                    return true;
                });
            });
        }

        return () => { 
            if( formControl ) {
                Object.keys(inputValue).forEach( attribute => formControl.unsubscribe(attribute) );
            }
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div class="form-field">
            <input
                type="text"
                value={getValue('attr_one')}
                onChange={ e => setValue('attr_one', e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={getValue('attr_two')}
                onChange={ e => setValue('attr_two', !!e.target.checked)}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

And inside functions `setValue` and `getValue` I always have default values in `inputValue` - I can't get updated state inside this functions. How i can organize my code to solve this problem?

P. S.

1) With useCallback I have the same results:

```
const getValue = useCallback( ( attr ) => {
    return inputValue[attr];
}, [inputValue]);
const setValue = useCallback( ( attr, val ) => {
    if( attr === 'attr_one' ) {
        if( val === 'bar' && getValue(attr) !== 'foo' ) {
            val = 'foo bar';
        }
    }
    setInputValue( {...inputValue, [attr]: val} );
}, [inputValue]);
```

2) With useEffect functions `setValue` and `getValue` are unavailable at first render:

```
let getValue, setValue;
useEffect( () => {
    getValue = ( attr ) => {
        return inputValue[attr];
    }
    setValue = ( attr, val ) => {
        if( attr === 'attr_one' ) {
            if( val === 'bar' && getValue(attr) !== 'foo' ) {
                val = 'foo bar';
            }
        }
        setInputValue( {...inputValue, [attr]: val} );
    }
}, [inputValue]);
```

Comment: Why does your `setValue()` have seemingly random logic in it?

Comment: It's just example - this function has some logic. I wanted to make the code shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: Your `useEffect` is capturing your `inputValue`, that's why it's always the same.  Try passing `inputValue` into your use effect array `[]`

Comment: use a Ref callback for formControl.subscribe... listeners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) to extract your logic into separate units of code. Since your state changes rely in part on the previous state, you should call [`useReducer()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead of `useState()` to make the implementation easier and the state changes atomic:

```js
const useAccessors = initialState => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((prev, [attr, val]) => {
    if (attr === 'attr_one') {
      if (val === 'bar' && getValue(attr) !== 'foo') {
        val = 'foo bar';
      }
    }

    return { ...prev, [attr]: val };
  }, initialState);
  const ref = useRef(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = state;
  }, [ref]);

  const getValue = useCallback(
    attr => ref.current[attr],
    [ref]
  );
  const setValue = useCallback((attr, val) => {
    dispatch([attr, val]);
  }, [dispatch]);

  return { getValue, setValue, ref };
};
```

Now your `useEffect()` is omitting dependencies from the second argument. This tends to cause problems like you're currently experiencing. We can employ [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to work around this.

Let's move your `useEffect()` into a custom hook as well and fix it:

```js
const useFormControl = (formControl, { getValue, setValue, ref }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (formControl) {
      const keys = Object.keys(ref.current);

      keys.forEach(attribute => {
        formControl.subscribeToValueCollecting(attribute, () => {
          return getValue(attribute);
        });
        formControl.subscribeToValueChange(attribute, value => {
          setValue(attribute, value);
          return true;
        });
      });

      return () => {
        keys.forEach(attribute => {
          formControl.unsubscribe(attribute);
        });
      };
    }
  }, [formControl, getValue, setValue, ref]);
};
```

Since `getValue`, `setValue`, and `ref` are memoized, the only dependency that actually changes is `formControl`, which is good.

Putting all this together, we get:

```
const MyComponent = props =>
  const { attrOneDefault, attrTwoDefault, formControl } = props;

  const { getValue, setValue, ref } = useAccessors({
    attr_one: attrOneDefault,
    attr_two: attrTwoDefault
  });

  useFormControl(formControl, { getValue, setValue, ref });

  return (
    <div class="form-field">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={getValue('attr_one')}
        onChange={e => setValue('attr_one', e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={getValue('attr_two')}
        onChange={e => setValue('attr_two', e.target.checked)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: @AlexShul I have to ask, did you implement those `subscribeToValueCollecting()` and `subscribeToValueChange()` methods? If not, what are they really called, and what library do they come from? That could potentially help me to avoid mutating the object in order to achieve reasonable performance.

Comment: Yes, I implement this methods in custom hook useFormControl. This hook helps validate forms and submit data. It passed from parent component. Hook code here: https://github.com/alex-shul/custom-components/blob/master/hook/Form.js

Comment: Any suggestions or commits for performance improvement are welcome.

Comment: @AlexShul I know it's been a long time but I just saw this answer again recently and thought it deserved an update. There's no need to mutate your state in order to get good performance, this is what `useRef()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const getValue = ( attr ) => {
        return inputValue[attr];
    }
const getValueRef = useRef(getValue)
const setValue = ( attr, val ) => {
        setInputValue( inputValue =>{
            if( attr === 'attr_one' ) {
                if( val === 'bar' && inputValue[attr] !== 'foo' ) {
                    val = 'foo bar';
                }
            }
            return {...inputValue, [attr]: val} );
        }
}

useEffect(()=>{
    getValueRef.current=getValue
})

    useEffect( () => {
        const getCurrentValue = (attr)=>getValueRef.current(attr)
        if( formControl ) {         
            Object.keys(inputValue).forEach( attribute => {
                formControl.subscribeToValueCollecting( attribute, () => {
                    return getCurrentValue(attribute);
                });
                formControl.subscribeToValueChange( attribute, ( value ) => {
                    setValue( attribute, value );
                    return true;
                });
            });
        }

        return () => { 
            if( formControl ) {
                Object.keys(inputValue).forEach( attribute => formControl.unsubscribe(attribute) );
            }
        }
    }, []);
```